# Error when counting rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I am sending in the email to the parameter of my checkEmail method which is in my authentication class.

authentication.cs:

```
public int checkEmail(string email)
{
    usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter user = new usersTableAdapters.UsersTableAdapter();
    users.UsersDataTable userDataTable = user.GetData();
    user.checkEmail(email);

    if (userDataTable.Rows == 0)
    {
    }

}
```

The checkEmail is a query which is "SELECT COUNT(email) AS email FROM People WHERE (email = ?)"

In the checkEmail method I am trying to check whether their was rows retrieved or not, however with this current code I get this error:

**Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' and 'int**

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: ``userDataTable.Rows.Count``

Comment: also are you forgetting a `return userDataTable.Rows.Count` in your method..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `userDataTable.Rows` isn't an integer, it's a collection of Rows. If you need the number of rows, you'd have to use the `Count` property.

You'll end up with this:

```
if(userDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Rows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) is a collection called `DataRowCollection`, you need to check the [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
if (userDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
```

Comment: Given what the SQL looks like I'd argue for ExecuteScalar instead of using a DataAdapter and DataTable

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add Count:

```
if (userDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
{
}
```

Comment: You'd do well to add additional context so that the user can understand how you are telling them to modify their code.

Answer (score 0):

The Rows property of the DataTable is a collection of DataRow objects. Change your code to:

```
if (userDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
{
...
}
```